# how to reduce fat model using concerned_with concept in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, rubygems

Right now I am working on rails 3 application. I want to reduce my fat model. I am tying to use concerned_with plugin. it's not working properly. please help me

plugin path https://github.com/matid/concerned_with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use that plugin. Its too old and abandoned (4years? 9 commits? good lord!!). If you are trying to re-factoring, that is thinning down you models 
try the methods shown in this blog post.
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/
You can use `reform` gem or `virtus` to extract form behaviours from your models. There are couple of episode on railscasts, but they are not free :(